# Cannot add itemized list to cventry?

Tags: errors, pdftex, texstudio, itemize

This code builds:

```
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\vspace*{-0.6cm}
\makecvtitle
\vspace{-0.7cm}

%\section{Master thesis}
%\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
%\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
%\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Work Experience \newline}
\cventry{Jan.2020-Present}{dev}{\newline fullstack dev}{}{}
...
```

while, after adding an itemized list,

```
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\vspace*{-0.6cm}
\makecvtitle
\vspace{-0.7cm}

%\section{Master thesis}
%\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
%\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
%\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Work Experience \newline}
\cventry{Sep.2020-Present}{dev}{fullstack dev}{\begin{itemize}
        \item done this
        \item done that
        \item done everything
\end{itemize}}{}{}
...
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 80.
You have requested package `moderncvheadi', but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.
You have requested package `moderncvbodyi', but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
```

Line 80 is where the itemized list ends:

```
\end{itemize}}{}{}
```

Why is this error thrown?

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Please make your code snippet be compilable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items can only be added to the last entry of a `\cventry` ...